# How to run atom from a directory in windows

Tags: atom-editor

I want to open Atom editor from a directory like I do with VS code or git bash as shown in the image

[image: Like This Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to add atom to your system path.
To do that ,

1)Open the run dialog (win + r), type "SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe" and hit enter. Here you should select "Environment Variables..." and edit the Path for your user.

2)Select and edit the variable path copy add this command `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\atom\bin` in the the environment variable.

3)Now open your git bash in the desired directory and run `atom.1` .